# How to stop loading an embeded youtube video after it is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, embed

How to stop the youtube video loading, once i have paused it?

Once I pause the video, the video loading-progress bar should also stop.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ggh_y-33Eso" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Reload the iframe source although this is bad, or use iframe API

Comment: are you using iframe like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmogpK

Comment: yes i am using iframe only

Comment: Place your code in your question

Comment: That is called buffering in Youtube, It has predefined values of few minutes of video it will buffer even after we pause it.
For more details refer [Youtube IFRAME API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: yes i need to stop buffering in youtube my page , is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
You may want to review through the Youtube JavaScript API Reference docs.

When you embed your video(s) on the page, you will need to pass this parameter:

http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1
If you want a stop all videos button, you can setup a javascript routine to loop through your videos and stop them:

player.stopVideo()
This does involve keeping track of all the page IDs for each video on the page. Even simpler might be to make a class and then use jQuery.each.

$('#myStopClickButton').click(function(){
  $('.myVideoClass').each(function(){
    $(this).stopVideo();
  });
});
```

Comment: i did'nt understand, I want stop loading when i pause the youtube embed video